# ASP.NET MVC: Can't register or login after the site has been hosted on azure

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

The site was working fine on the server and after I hosted it on azure. I can't login or register a new user...
http://alibabastore.azurewebsites.net/

Where is the problem ? Please

An error occurred while processing your request.

Comment: You'll need to turn off custom error, so that we can see the exception.

Comment: I need to turn off custom error in the visual studio or on azure????

Comment: Are you logging errors in application? You can go thru the log files to see what exception or error is causing the issue? The database connection string is correct on azure?

Comment: I tested the connection string while i was hosting on azure...i believed is correct. But the way i could not find the custom error on web.config. I went thru it and I did not find any custom error. Where is located?????